# How to group the same element in list into a specific column

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby, group

I have this 2d array:

```
info = [["A", "B", "C", "D", "nan"], 
       ["A", "C", "D", "B", "E"], 
       ["C", "D", "A", "B", "K"]]

col = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

abc_df = pd.DataFrame(info, columns=col)

abc_df
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   A   B   C   D   nan
1   A   C   D   B   E
2   C   D   A   B   K
```

What I want it would be is:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   C   B   A   D   nan
1   C   B   A   D   E
2   C   B   A   D   K
```

How can I regroup it into the specific column this above output? I don't need it to be sorted, but at least it can group in the same column. I have tried many way, using if-else statement, sorted function and etc. But it's not worked.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @timgeb sorry for that. I have edited the question. Can you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not fill the columns in the loop with the desired elements. If you meant something else let me know.

```
bbb = ['C', 'B', 'A', 'D']

for i in range(0, len(abc_df.columns)-1):
    abc_df[abc_df.columns[i]] = bbb[i]
```

Output

```
   1  2  3  4    5
0  C  B  A  D  nan
1  C  B  A  D    E
2  C  B  A  D    K
```

Comment: That is not what I mean. I already have the data and would not added what desired. All I need is to rearrange the same data within a column.

Comment: And can I know why there is -1 in the loop?

Comment: This is so that the last column is not filled.